# Place elements in single line in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set my logo in between the menu. I am able to add logo but not able to make it work properly. My logo shows in a single line but all the other menu items show in a line. I want to show the whole menu in a line. Here is my website link: http://savourthemoment.fr/home

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be better if you actually shared the relevant code for the issue you are facing.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two modifications to be done.
1. The link which contains your image element is 1040 px wide. I changed it to:

```
a{
    width: 104px;
}
```

However its better to reference it using an id or class rather than using the anchor tag as it will manipulate width of all the anchor tags.

2. The width of the image is set at 10 %. Change it to a 100% so that it occupies the entire width of its parent element.

   img.savour-home-logo{
           width:100%;
       }

[image: Here's a snapshot of the website]